# Placing <div> on same line as image

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML that looks like the following: http://jsfiddle.net/KbqHa/

I would like this `div` to be on the same line as the image. However, it moves to the line below due to the div being a block element. In this case I'd usually use a `<span>`, but this completely messes up the border (and the `div` wraps under the image too). Adding `display:inline-block` to the `div` doesn't seem to work either. I've tried using `float: left` but I can't get that to work either. Any thoughts?

Comment: What exactly do you mean "to be on the same line"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The classic solution is to use `float: left` on the `img`, and then add a `margin-left` to the `div` equal to the width of the image.

**See**: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/KbqHa/2/

However, that's no good if the width of the image is unknown.

So, a better solution is to use `overflow: hidden` on the `div`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/KbqHa/3/

The reason this seemingly nonsensical solution works is explained [here](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats).