# How do I position text wrapped in divs next to each other?

Tags: html, css

I want this text all on one line, not spaced on two sepearate lines. How can it be done?

```
<div id="titlefont">
    <div id="boldness">This text</div>should be next to each other
</div>​
```

```
#titlefont {
       font-family:arial;
       font-size:30px;
       text-align:center;
       color:#35404c;
}

 #boldness {
       font-weight:bold;
       font-style:italic; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nfSku/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `div`s are rendered as block elements which clear any other elements when not floated.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/eu7AW/

CSS:

```
#boldness {
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:italic; 
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always `float` the `div`s or add the `display` property when trying to show objects in the same horizontal line.
[Read here if you want to align images and text on the same line.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718761/placing-div-on-same-line-as-image)

Comment: thank you Ecko. I actually tried to do floating first, but the way my layout was setup, the elments then jumped into a div that was below the line. I have my layout setup like.. title at the top, then a div below it holding 3 more divs. when i tried the float on this text, it just jumped into the div in the box below lol, so i was like.. i need to goto stack right now

Comment: Okay. For that you have to use `display : inline-block` to the `div` on the left . Also, sometimes you need to specify `float: left` or `float:right` to both the `div`s; both on the left as well as on the right one.