# Using CSS for flexible layout with one fixed width element

Tags: html, css

I've been thinking about this problem and can't seem to find the ideal solution.

Let's say I have a div tag with flexible width. In that div, I have 2 more divs, one next to the other either using float, absolute position or any other attribute that will work. The first div has a fixed width, say 100px. The second div must take 100% of whatever horizontal space is left.

I tried having both float left, first div width: 100px second div position: absolute, left: 100px, width: 100% but the second div would be too long and have 100px extra width. It would be nice if css allows something like width: 100%-100px.

Comment: Let's say you posted your code and then we say that someone could help you.

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809079/two-divs-side-by-side-one-100-width-others-width-depended-on-content/6809143#6809143. There's also the margin approach, which works fine provided that the width of the left `div` is fixed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718761/placing-div-on-same-line-as-image/7718824#7718824

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can with css3

```
width: calc(100% - 100px);
```

**Edit:** here you can see the browser support http://caniuse.com/calc

Comment: Do note that while this is a good solution, browser support for `calc()` is not great and some sort of fallback should be used too

Comment: @Novocaine88 Yes, for sure! I've added a link to browser support

Comment: Thanks, did not know that. Which reminds me, I should take a look at all the new things in CSS3.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to see:
[Expand a div to take the remaining width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260122/expand-div-to-take-remaining-width)

It explains a concept called as "block formatting context" ..you can have a fixed block on either left or right of your "expanding" div